# How to get time difference between two events in SQL

Tags: sql, date-arithmetic

I have a data table with these columns:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yZwu.png)
where

- datetime: event in_time and Out_time
- Severity: unique for each message
- Message: event message like= BLOWER TRIP ALARM,CIRCULATION PUMP TRIP ALARM,DEOILING CONV TRIP ALARM,ELEVATOR TRIP ALARM,CROSS CONV TRIP ALARM
- Active: if the event on then active will be 1 else 0

I have to identify the difference between the event in time and out time.

I have tried using a CTE and using a separate table for event intime and outtime:

Using this command (for event intime):

```
SELECT 
    [DATETIME], [Severity], [Message], [Active], [Acked]
INTO
    intime
FROM 
    [master].[dbo].[DATATABLE] 
WHERE 
    ACTIVE = 1
```

Now my data table with the event intime is "intime". The table with OUTTIME record is:

```
SELECT 
    [DATETIME], [Severity], [Message], [Active], [Acked]
INTO
    OUTIME
FROM 
    [master].[dbo].[DATATABLE] 
WHERE 
    ACTIVE = 0
```

How can I get the time event base difference between both tables?

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Key is Message column -- need to match Elevator InTime with Elevator OutTime  (not with Blower OutTime).  Need to account for two Elevator InTime-s in a row without an intervening Elevator OutTime, or two OutTime-s in a row...